# Узнать какое видео воспроизводится?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть много видео. Как узнать id видео которое воспроизводилось при запуске нового видео, у всех разный id, хотелось бы получить этот id.

```js
function playPause(id) {
var gif = document.getElementById(id);
$('video').each(function() {
    if(id != this.id && this.paused == false) { //this.id - id видео которое воспроизводилось (То что искал и для чего задавался вопрос.)
            this.pause();
    }
});
if (gif.paused) {
    gif.play();
} else {
    gif.pause();
}
}
```

```html
<video id='gif<?php echo $article['id'] ?>' onclick='playPause(this.id)' loop>
    <source src='gifs/3e0d796625761fb1967746649011d2ce.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Все. Решено.
Может кому пригодиться. Код воспроизводит только одно видео на сайте, при запуске другого предыдущее ставит на паузу.

Comment: На каком сайте хотя бы?

Comment: Сайта еще нет. Только пишу, точнее пробую.

Comment: Можно хранить id видио как атрибут какого-нибудь тэга или инпут с типом hidden

Comment: Так вы ведь и так получаете id воспроизводимого видео, когда вызываете playPause(). Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Да, текущего, а мне нужно было предыдущего (с этим вопросом получилось разобраться ). Но сейчас другая проблема видео которое уже воспроизводится не ставится на паузу, при нажатие на него, только если включаю другое видео, не могу понять  почему.

Comment: @VladVityuk у вас в вопросе, скорее всего, опечатка. Исправьте ее - тогда вопрос будет более понятен.

Comment: @VladVityuk "Как узнать или какое-то видео воспроизводится" - вот с этим не понятно...

Comment: Исправил. Надеюсь так понятней.

Comment: Чуть-чуть не успел с ответом)

Comment: Может Ваш ответ будет лучше моего решения, хотелось бы увидеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. вам нужно было "запомнить" `id` предыдущего воспроизводимого видео, могу предложить такой вариант:

```js
function playPause(id) {
  var gif = document.getElementById(id);
  $('video').each(function() {
    if (this.paused == false) {
      var previousVideo = $(this).get(0);
      if (this.id != id) {
        previousVideo.pause();
      }
      console.log(previousVideo.id);
    }
  });
  if (gif.paused) {
    gif.play();
  } else {
    gif.pause();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id='gif1' onclick='playPause(this.id)' loop>
    <source src='https://ak0.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3671960/preview/stock-footage-flight-over-clouds-loop-able-animation.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>

<video id='gif2' onclick='playPause(this.id)' loop>
    <source src='https://ak7.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3711827/preview/stock-footage-high-quality-looping-animation-of-ocean-waves-from-underwater-with-floating-plankton-light-rays-shi.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>

<video id='gif3' onclick='playPause(this.id)' loop>
    <source src='https://ak0.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3507950/preview/stock-footage-natural-green-motion-background-seamless-loop.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Comment: какой смысл передавать id и потом по нему искать, если можно сразу элемент передавать?

Comment: @Grundy код взят из примера - видимо, ТС'у так нужно было